# Error 405 ó Your POST request is not being received quickly enought. Please retry

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

Estoy enviando una petición HTTP pero se demora en llegar la petición con este codigo:

> r3 = requests.post(url_a_extraer, data = query_consultar, cookies = cookies)

y me sale la siguiente respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es ¿como recibo esa respuesta del servidor, siempre? ya que aveces si la recibe

Comment: tu codigo esta bien , lo que debes configurar es tu servidor el timeout

Comment: si seria lo mejor pero no tengo control de ese servidor.

Comment: `r3 = requests.post(url_a_extraer, data = query_consultar, cookies = cookies , timeout=10)` , existe un parametro timeout modificalo puedes ver mas en la [documentacion](http://docs.python-requests.org/es/latest/user/advanced.html)